# LFU cache implementation with remove keys method

Tags: caching, system-design

I'm trying to implement a LFU cache which along with the `put(key, val)` method also handles `remove(key)` method. I found handling `put` is comparatively easier than `remove` . Because in the later case, upon removing the existing key, I had to again sort all the existing keys.
I want to find some optimal way of handling `remove` keys method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use the [O(1) scheme](http://dhruvbird.com/lfu.pdf) to avoid sorting. The Caffeine simulator has an [implementation](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/ebec48e91f3b26475b7cfacfff3ccfe2242b86fc/simulator/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/simulator/policy/linked/FrequentlyUsedPolicy.java) for its hit rate analysis.